# Another one: sObject type is not supported

Tags: soql, soap-api, soap, enterprise-wsdl

What do I have:

1. custom object my__customObject__c from managed package. It is
   deployed.
2. service built using Enterprise WSDL.
3. Partial Copy sandbox

Service tries to execute 'SELECT Id FROM my__customObject__c' query using Administrator account (so there should be no problem with permissions)

It works perfectly in production, but fails in sandbox with:

```
INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'my__customObject__c' is not supported.
```

I tried to execute the same query using 3rd party tools and sandbox credentials (that I suppose uses Partner WSDL), and it executes perfectly.

UPD1. there is also custom object 'customObject__c'

Comment: did you try the same query without namesepace?

Comment: try like `SELECT Id FROM customObject__c`

Comment: @Ratan there is another custom object with name customObject__c

Comment: @Ashwani object name without namespace is ambiguous. so I cannot query it. There are my__customObject__c in 'my' package and customObject__c

Comment: After downloading latest WSDL and regenerating SOAP client code I found query is executed on production and sandbox instances.
But I cannot found any explanation for that, my__customObject__c node in WSDL hasn't been changed.

Comment: Your endpoint address at the end of the WSDL contains an ID that encodes selection of managed package versions. Could it be that the staging login URL had an older version of it  before you updated the WSDL? Seems like a possible explanation given the info above.

Comment: @spacemanspiff yes, but this custom object was not modified for years